# Handling double quotes in document.getElementById

Tags: javascript, html, string

I am trying to fetch a JSON String from a hidden html input.
JSON string:

```
"{
    \"title\": \"Air Quality Details\",
    \"type\": \"object\",
    \"properties\": {
        \"lead\": {
            \"type\": \"string\",
            \"title\": \"Lead\"
        },
            \"nitrogen\": {
            \"type\": \"string\",
            \"title\": \"Nitrogen\"
        }

    }
}"
```

`<input type="hidden" id="uischema" value="{
    \" title\":="" \"air="" quality="" details\",="" \"type\":="" \"object\",="" 
 \"properties\":="" {="" \"lead\":="" \"string\",="" \"title\":="" \"lead\"="" 
 },="" \"nitrogen\":="" \"nitrogen\"="" }="" }"="">`

when i do document.getElementById on this, I get only "{\" instead of the complete string.

Comment: please show the hidden input

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) It's very hard to help you if you don't **show the HTML**.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're doing this:

```
<input type="hidden" id="something" value="{\"title\":...
```

In HTML, `\` isn't an escape character, so that first `"` ends the `value` attribute, exactly as though you'd written `value="{\"`.

To properly include JSON in a double-quoted attribute, you'd use `&quot;`:

```
<input type="hidden" id="something" value="{&quot;title&quot;:...
```

**But**, putting JSON in a hidden input is probably not a good idea. If you just want to make the data available on the page, output it to a `script` tag or similar.

Answer (score 0):

The string in your example, cannot have newlines like that. Instead, you should replace the newlines with `\n`, and then it should work correctly.

Alternatively, if you are able to use ES6 features, you can use use use backticks to surround your string, and then you will be able to have a multi line string in your code.

Comment: The OP said this is in the value of a hidden input. Newlines in attributes are just fine.